# Kubernetes REST API

Tags: api, kubernetes

Does kubernetes accessible via a REST API? I was looking over at the [Kubernetes API](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/api.html) page and it all looks very cryptic / incomplete. They talk about new versions but have not disclosed the API usage or docs anywhere. I just wanted to know if there is a way to access the cluster information in any other way other than using the `kubectl` command.

Example usage:

What I do now:

`kubectl get pod --context='my-prod-cluster'`

What I'd like to do:

`curl GET /some/parameters/to/get/info`

Answer (score 47):

You can see all the API calls kubectl is making by passing `--v=8` to any kubectl command

Comment: I get `Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'v' in -v=8` when I run `kubectl get pods --context='vagrant' -v=8`

Comment: Works. is there any resource which shows how to extract info using REST calls? I still dont follow the official documentation, its pretty confusing and they do not have any kind of sample usage which could help me see where I am going wrong

Answer (score 2):

The REST API is fully documented on the Kubernetes website:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/

It includes info on how to [reach the API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/accessing-the-api/), [be authorized to use the API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/), and a full breakdown of what API objects are available and what operations you can do on them.

Comment: The links are out of date

Comment: main link out of date (its forever changing, so annoying):
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/

Answer (score 1):

The API is available to you outside of `kubectl`. In fact, my understanding is that underneath it all `kubectl` is just making REST calls to the API server. In a cluster using TLS certificates for authentication, a curl call to list your pods might look something like this (you can get your apiserver location/port with `kubectl cluster-info | grep 'Kubernetes master'`):

```
curl --cert myuser.pem --key myuser-key.pem --cacert /path/to/ca.pem https://my-prod-cluster-apiserver:6443/api/v1/pods
```

[This doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/http-proxy-access-api/) shows how to use `kubectl proxy` to allow you to explore the Swagger-generated API docs on your own cluster.

Comment: I couldn't find a swagger/openAPI file at the link referencing the generated docs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is maybe what you find , though it is not always up to date.
http://kubernetes.io/kubernetes/third_party/swagger-ui/

Comment: I couldn't find a swagger/openAPI file at this link

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes has an API reference page. It details all the operations accessible via the API. To access your cluster's API locally, make sure to proxy in, using `kubectl proxy` (after set-up of course).

API Reference: 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/