# Kubernetes REST API - Unauthorized

Tags: rest, api, kubernetes, authorization

I have following Kubernetes REST API request

```
GET https://theserver/api/v1/pods?includeUninitialized=true
```

and included following HTTP Headers in the request:

```
Authorization: Basic ***************
Accept: application/json, */*
User-Agent: kubectl.exe/v1.13.0 (windows/amd64) kubernetes/ddf47ac
```

Result is the following error

```
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "reason": "Unauthorized",
    "code": 401
}
```

I already tried the following:

- Analog kubectl request "kubectl describe pods --all-namespaces" works fine (but I need REST)
- Used "--v=12" parameter as in newkind101's comment to [Kubernetes REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024969/kubernetes-rest-api) to see the underlying REST API calls - looks same as mine
- Read Kubernetes Documentation - but I failed to find detail information which HTTP headers or/and HTTP body values to send to authenticate properly (few thing I could retrieve from curl sample calls in that docs)
- I read [Access Kubernetes API using REST APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808927/access-kubernetes-api-using-rest-apis) but want to understand my issue before I use a framework like GoDaddy

kubectl seems to do a bit more than I can see with the "--v=12" parameter. This bit is likely connected to things in ".kube/config" file. Still I don't know what exactly and where to put in my HTTP request.

Comment: How have you setup authentication for your cluster? If you want to understand the topic more -> https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/

Comment: Good point, thanks. I did not setup the cluster myself, I just received Url and credentials ("Basic ******") to program against. I assume Url and credentials are correct as these work with kubectl.exe from the command-line. Though, I will have this double-checked on Monday.

Comment: Answer regarding auth setup: Yes, for the simple setup this goes out of the box via AAD integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember [Basic authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#static-password-file) method is disabled by default and needs to be enabled by adding `--basic-auth-file` flag to the API server configuration, therefore all requests to REST API are identified as [anonymous user](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#anonymous-requests) and might be resulted in `401 Unauthorized` error.